# Linear regression / line finding for non-function lines

Tags: math, geometry, numerical

I want to find a line having a number of points which are around that line. Line is in 2D space and is defined by two points, or by one point and an angle. What would be the algorithm for it?

There's a lot about this on SO and in internet and also in Numerical Receipes, but all examples seem to focus on function form of the line (y=ax+b) which is not going to work well for (almost) vertical lines.

I could possibly detect if the line is more horizontal or more vertical, and swap coordinates in the other case, but maybe there exists some more elegant solution?

I'm using C# ATM but can translate from any code probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry I can't provide a reference, but here's how:

Suppose your N (2d) data points are p[] and you want to find a vector a and a scalar d to minimise

```
E = Sum{ i | sqr( a'*p[i] - d) }/N
```

(The line is { q | a'*q = d}  E is the sum of the squares of the distances of the data points from the line).

Some tedious algebra shows that

```
 E = a'*C*a + sqr(d - a'*M)
```

where M is the mean and C the covariance of the data, ie

```
 M = Sum{ i | p[i] } / N
 C = Sum{ i | (p[i]-M)*(p[i]-M)' } / N
```

E will be minimised by choosing d = a'*M, and a to be an eigenvector of C corresponding to the smaller eigenvalue.

So the algorithm is:

Compute M and C

Find the smaller eigenvalue of C and the corresponding eigenvector a

Compute d = a'*M

(Note that the same thing works in higher dimensions too. For example in 3d we would find the 'best' plane).

Comment: And here is the [reference](http://stat.smmu.edu.cn/history/pearson1901.pdf). Or if you prefer the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis). Depending on how many eigenvectors you use, you may also get the best line in 3D.

Comment: Thank you for this. It looks like I'm going to have a hard time converting this to code, but I'll try and let you know how well I did.